# How to convert a vertical list to horizontal (using Bootstrap and media queries)?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

Been trying to convert this list to horizontal for a small screen size. Tried many things but nothing worked. This may be simple but I'm starting Bootstrap and was creating a Layout Shifter pattern.

Here are the HTML and CSS for the code.

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: #E57373;
}

li {
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
  .menu li {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <ul>
          <li><a style="cursor: pointer;">Home</a></li>
          <li><a style="cursor: pointer;">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a style="cursor: pointer;">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color: #FFCDD2">
      <p>The layout shifter pattern is the most responsive pattern, with multiple breakpoints across several screen widths. Key to this layout is the way content moves about, instead of reflowing and dropping below other columns. Due to the significant differences
        between each major breakpoint, it is more complex to maintain and likely involves changes within elements, not just overall content layout.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

- https://jsfiddle.net/nerq0ero/

For testing purposes, I changed the media query to `max-width: 900px;`. You can set it back to whatever it needs to be.

Basically, I just added `display: flex;` to the `<ul>` element. I also centered the text on the `<li>` element. If you don't want the menu to stretch across the screen, you can set some sort of width to it. Let me know if I can assist any further!

```
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: #E57373;
}

li {
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
  .menu li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu ul {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you have specified `display: flex` on `.container`.

Flex properties only work between parent and child elements.

So when you make `.container` a flex container, that means that `.row`, its only child, becomes a flex item. The nav items are never flex-aligned because flex properties are not inherited by elements further down the tree structure.

So try this instead:

```
.container ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media ( max-width: 800px ) {
  .container ul { flex-direction: row; }
}
```

```css
.container ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #E57373;
}

@media ( max-width: 800px ) {
  .container ul { flex-direction: row; }
  .container ul li { margin: 5px; }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <ul>
          <li><a style="cursor: pointer;">Home</a></li>
          <li><a style="cursor: pointer;">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a style="cursor: pointer;">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/376fg1t8/)

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

Change li tag style **display: block** to **display: inline-block**  for a particular screen.

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?:

https://jsfiddle.net/g45qq2jx/

Here the `li`s are block elements on the small screen and inline-blocks (with some `margin` to get some distance between them and better vertical positioning) on wider screens (I used 600px for the media query). Additionally, I added `padding: 0` to the `ul` to avoid its default padding.